# Make Alfresco Web Script show error 500 as JSON rather than HTML

Tags: json, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, http-status-code-500

I am writing an Alfresco Web Script that will be consumed by external computers.

When I throw a WebScriptException, I would like the error 500 to come with an error page in JSON, rather than HTML, so that the external computers can parse it. Right now I am getting this:

[image: Web Script error 500]

How to get JSON instead?

I see that some Web Scripts manage to produce error pages as JSON (for error 401 though, so probably before the Web Script actually gets called):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a freemarker dedicated for each status code. If you go to this web page http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/ws-component-name.html and scroll to "FreeMarker Templates - Response status", you can see some examples.

Quoting as of 5.2:

> Response status code document file names adhere to a naming convention
>   as defined by the Web Script Framework. The appropriate response
>   status code template is searched for in the following order:
>
> - A template located in the same folder as the web script description document for rendering a specific status code response,
>     which adheres to the naming convention `<web script id>.<http method>.<format>.<status code>.ftl`
> - A template located in the same folder as the web script description document for rendering a response of any status code,
>     which adheres to the naming convention `<web script id>.<http method>.<format>.status.ftl`
> - A package-level template located in the package of the web script but, if not found, is searched for in the parent package hierarchy, up
>     to the root package for rendering a response of any status code, which
>     adheres to the naming convention `<format>.status.ftl`
> - A template located in the root package for rendering an HTML response for the specific status code, which adheres to the naming
>     convention `<status code>.ftl`
> - A template located in the root package for rendering an HTML response of any status code, which adheres to the naming convention:
>     `status.ftl`

Comment: So the filename must be `<web script id>.<http method>.json.500.ftl` if I understand correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're correct.Couple of samples here.
hello-world.get.html.412.ftl
hello-world.post.html.500.ftl