# Web Script error 500 template ignored

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I wrote an Alfresco Web Script that renders CSV, it works well.

In a particular case, I want the Web Script to [return an error 500 as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42433681/226958), so I wrote a `.json.500.ftl` template for it.

**PROBLEM:** The error 500 always shows up as HTML (the default Web Script error template).
What did I do wrong?

My files:

```
auditlog.get.desc.xml
auditlog.get.csv.ftl
auditlog.get.json.500.ftl
```

`auditlog.get.json.500.ftl` just contains  `{"error": "abc is not correct"}`

`auditlog.get.desc.xml` contains:

```
<webscript>
    <shortname>Audit Log Web Script</shortname>
    <description>Returns audit data for a given day</description>
    <url>/theapp/auditlog</url>
    <authentication>admin</authentication>
    <format default="csv"></format>
</webscript>
```

All of these files are in `tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/` and I have restarted Alfresco.

Comment: Try to call like this, http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/<ur extra namesapce any>theapp/auditlog?format=json   I added the format=json at the last. But it may affect the original request param of format.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan: That correctly returns the JSON. I was hoping to get CSV if everything goes well, but get JSON only in case of error 500... maybe Web Script technology is not meant to do that?

Comment: If you're using Java backed webscript, IIRC, you can override the webscript return format to JSON. Refer `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript` and `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.renderFormatTemplate(String, Map<String, Object>, Writer)` method.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan: `DeclarativeWebScri‌​pt.renderFormatTempl‌​ate` is `final`, so I guess I must extend `AbstractWebScript`? (currently my Java code extends `DeclarativeWebScript`)

Answer (score 2):

```
<format default="csv"></format>
```

Above line will try to fetch template with "auditlog.get.csv.500.ftl" name,which is not there in your case.

It will only try to fetch different response template if you are passing different  parameter in url, something like below.

"http://localhost:8080/share/service/demo/webscript?format=json"

Comment: So your conclusion is that my requirement (same request returns CSV is OK, JSON is KO) is not implementable without tweaking the Web Scripts system, right?

Comment: didn't get you.

Comment: First, you didn't mentions anything anout html template,2nd is if server return 500 error it will render 500.ftl, as you defined that.I think you should read about how <format default="csv"></format> tag works in descriptor.

Comment: Indeed writing `<format default="csv"></format>` was my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: The same Web Script must return CSV if things go well, but JSON if things go wrong. I can not ask people to use a different URL, because when launching the request they don't know yet whether things will go right or wrong.